# How to grep a file for text with apostrophes?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

people... Im coding a linux bash file and I need it to grep for the text `'Josh''1234`. Is there any way to ignore those apostrophes? heres what I tried:
(Josh is set as `usr` and 1234 as `pas`.)

```
if grep -q '\'$usr\'\'$pas\''; then
    echo username and password correct
else
    echo INCORECT
    sleep 10
fi
```

Comment: This is misleading. These are single quotes and not apostrophes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just quote with double quotes, so that single quotes can be included normally:

```
grep "'$usr''$pas"
#    ^           ^
#     ^    ^^
#     single quotes to match
```

Comment: Or if `"` is hard to remember, `.` is only half as hard: `grep .$usr..$pas` This solution provided by the QND solutions. Man, I really got to do something more productive... This comment will self destruct in...

Comment: I suggest to add a `.`  after `$pas`.

Comment: Why, @Cyrus ? It is a bit confusing how OP addresses it: he mentions `'Josh''1234` (without any extra char after the pass) but then `'\'$usr\'\'$pas\''`.

Comment: @JamesBrown the good thing of `"` is that it will keep working if the pass or usr contains a space.

Comment: @fedorqui: Good catch.

Comment: NOTE: I may add another question related to this exact line of code, if so a link will be posted on this page. XD